# Entity Framework 4.2 Code First Features

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net

I would like to know what features are included in the newest release of `entity framework 4.2` using the `code first approach`?  I have searched and haven't found much.

I am interested in using stored procedures.  Does EF 4.2 code first support this feature yet?  Any articles that I can read to help me on my way, I did Google and could not find much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no new features in EF 4.2 - it is fixed version of EF 4.1 Update 1:

- It provides fix to [issue with broken backward compatibility](http://ayende.com/blog/75777/entity-framework-4-1-update-1-backward-compatibility-and-microsoft) introduced in EF 4.1 Update 1

[EF 4.1 Update 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/07/25/ef-4-1-update-1-released.aspx) contained minor bug fixes and new types for context factory implementation.

ADO.NET team has also [changed versioning](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/08/11/next-ef-release-plans.aspx) so EF 4.2 is not release of June 2011 CTP - this CTP will be [probably part of .NET 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/10/18/how-we-talk-about-ef-and-its-future-versions.aspx) because separate release of EF core libraries didn't work as expected.

New features introduced in June 2011 CTP didn't contain any support for Stored procedures in code only mapping.

Comment: @Ok thanks.  I thought they would support stored procedures by this time.  Do you think they will ever support stored procedures for EF code first?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to type in your name above :)